# Node.js crashing on wrong file path

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server

I just started learning Node.js and Express, and I'm currently trying to build a static file server. My question is: How do I prevent node from crashing every time the user inserts a wrong path? 
Here's my code:

```
var express=require('express')
var fs=require('fs')
var app=express()
var server=app.listen(3000, listening)
console.log('Server Started on Port 3000')

function listening(){
    console.log('Listening...')
}

app.use(express.static('website'))

app.get('/search/:page', goTo)


function goTo(req, res){
    var data=req.params
    fs.createReadStream('./website/'+data.page+'.html').pipe(res)
}
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

With [try-catch](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Sentencias/try...catch) your app will try to open the specified path. If it fails, your app will send an error instead of crashing.

Try this:

```
function goTo(req, res) {
    var data = req.params;
    try{
        fs.createReadStream('./website/'+data.page+'.html').pipe(res);
    } catch(err) {
        res.send(err);
    }
}
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: You should explain what you've done, since he's only just started out.